# Sum and order by desc with query builder (laravel)

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-builder

I have som results of multiple table, selected by

```
$places = Place::with(['rates' => function($query)
    {
        $query->select('id', 'place_id', 'criterion_id', 'value');

    }])->select('id', 'coords')->get();
```

I need to order this reslut by sum (or avg) of values. How can I do this? I tried to use

```
$query->select('id', 'place_id', 'criterion_id', 'value')->sum('value');
```

but it doesn't work.

[image: I have such table]

Comment: Please add the relevant database tables and fields. Also tell us a sample of the result you expect. Thanks!

Comment: @milz sample of result on screenshot

Comment: Great that you added the results, but @milz meant you should show the results you want, not the results you get.

Comment: @JoelHinz I need to sum (or avg, doesn't matter) values in "rates" and order desc places by it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is works to you. You can use `JOIN` instead of Eager Loading.

The code will be like this:

```
Place::leftJoin('rates', 'places.id', '=', 'rates.place_id')
          ->selectRaw('places.*, SUM(rates.value) as sumOfRateValues')
          ->groupBy('places.id')
          ->orderBy('sumOfRateValues', 'DESC')
          ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just pull all the information that you need and then use `sum` or `avg` when you need it, or set it as a variable after the query to pass it in to your view.

For example:

```
$places = Place::with(['rates' => function($query)
    {
        $query->select('id', 'place_id', 'criterion_id', 'value');

    }])->select('id', 'coords')->get();

$sum = $places['rates']->sum('value');
$avg = $places['rates']->avg('value');
```

Or if you want to do it in your view for each item:

```
@foreach ($places as $place)
{{ $place->rates->sum('value') }}
{{ $place->rates->avg('value') }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (but not the best) solution would be to sort collection as You want, like so:

```
    $places = Place::with([
        'rates' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'place_id', 'criterion_id', 'value');
        }
    ])->select('id', 'coords')->get()->sortByDesc(function ($item) {
        return $item->rates->sum('value'); //$item->rates->avg('value')
    });
```

The best solution would be to join rates table and sort by aggregate like `sum(rates.value)`.